# Tensorflow in DSX: Consuming prediction results fails due to list()

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science-experience

I have successfully built a model using Tensorflow in Python in IBM Data Science Experience. It works to evaluate test data using this model. However, when I invoke it to do a prediction on records, I cannot consume the result that evaluate returns. I follow the description from https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn and use list():

```
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_pandas_predict_data},
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

y = m.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)
predictions = list(p["predictions"] for p in itertools.islice(y, 6))
print("Predictions: {}".format(str(predictions)))
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
       <ipython-input-49-49a72bc2fad0> in <module>()
     15 # .predict() returns an iterator of dicts; convert to a list    and print
     16 # predictions
---> 17 predictions = list(p["predictions"] for p in itertools.islice(y, 6))
     18 print("Predictions: {}".format(str(predictions)))

  TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this?

Many thanks.

Johannes

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a variable called `list`, which shadows the standard python type `list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot - you are right. By accident, I used list as a variable name earlier in the program. I changed this. Now I get a different error message though:

    TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-14-f8637b385193> in <module>()
         16 # .predict() returns an iterator of dicts; convert to a list and print
         17 # predictions
    ---> 18 predictions = list(p["predictions"] for p in itertools.islice(y, 6))
...
TypeError: data must be either a numpy array or pandas DataFrame if pandas is installed; got dict

Comment: @Johannes, please open a new question for the new problem.

Comment: Thank you - this comment helped me resolve the issue. The data structure x_pandas_predict_data was not correct. I adapted it as follows and then it worked: x=pd.DataFrame({k: x_pandas_predict_data[k].values for k in FEATURES})